# Go Memory Usage with cipher.AEAD.Seal()

Tags: go, encryption, memory

I am encrypting data using Go's implementation of ChaCha20-Poly1305, but as I am encrypting some large files the memory usage is higher than I had expected. I understand that Go's implementation of AEAD ciphers means we have to hold the entire data in memory for it to create the hash, but the memory usage is double the size of the plaintext.

The following small program which attempts to encrypt 4 GiB of data highlights this (the `key` and `nonce` shouldn't be empty in a real world program):

```
package main

import (
  "os"
  "fmt"
  "runtime"
  "golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305"
)

func main() {
  showMemUsage("START")

  plaintext := make([]byte, 4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) // 4 GiB

  showMemUsage("STAGE 1")

  key := make([]byte, chacha20poly1305.KeySize)
  if cipher, err := chacha20poly1305.New(key); err == nil {
    showMemUsage("STAGE 2")

    nonce := make([]byte, chacha20poly1305.NonceSize)
    cipher.Seal(plaintext[:0], nonce, plaintext, nil)
  }

  showMemUsage("END")
}

func showMemUsage(tag string) {
  var m runtime.MemStats

  runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)
  fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "[%s] Alloc = %v MiB, TotalAlloc = %v MiB\n", tag, m.Alloc / 1024 / 1024, m.TotalAlloc / 1024 / 1024)
}
```

According to the source code of `crypto/cipher/gcm.go` (which is used by both AES-GCM and ChaCha20-Poly1305) there is the following comment:

```
// To reuse plaintext's storage for the encrypted output, use plaintext[:0]
// as dst. Otherwise, the remaining capacity of dst must not overlap plaintext.
Seal(dst, nonce, plaintext, additionalData []byte) []byte
```

This implies I should be able to re-use the memory, which I have attempted to do, but it makes no difference to the amount of memory that my application is using - after calling `Seal()` we always end up using 8 GiB of memory to encrypt 4 GiB of data?

```
[START] Alloc = 0 MiB, TotalAlloc = 0 MiB
[STAGE 1] Alloc = 4096 MiB, TotalAlloc = 4096 MiB
[STAGE 2] Alloc = 4096 MiB, TotalAlloc = 4096 MiB
[END] Alloc = 8192 MiB, TotalAlloc = 8192 MiB
```

If it was re-using the memory (as implied) then I shouldn't expect any massive increase except that AEAD ciphers add a relatively small hash to the ciphertext?

Comment: I don't really know go, but it seems to me that the comments and the interface are contradictory. The tag is placed at the end of the destination buffer, thus it seems like the destination buffer will always be larger than the plaintext input buffer and force a second allocation. Is there a way to allocate the storage but then set the length of `plaintext` to be `taglen` bytes smaller?

Comment: The length of the tag in ChaCha20-Poly1305 is 16 bytes, so the buffer would need to be expanded, but I thought there was a difference between the length of a slice and the capacity of a slice - the capacity would be `2x len(plaintext)` as I believe it doubles when expanding, but the length would be `len(plaintext) + 16`?

Comment: Just from googling it appears `make` has optional additional parameter for the length. You should try making the length 16 bytes less than the capacity.

Comment: I think you are on to something there.. I have just made it 16 bytes bigger, but didn't pass the last 16 bytes to `Seal()` (e.g. `cipher.Seal(plaintext[:0], nonce, plaintext[:(4 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) - 16], nil)`) and my memory usage stays the same. Looks like I need a way to ideally expand a slice by 16 bytes without the capacity doubling in size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to account for the authentication tag that is appended to the ciphertext. If you make room for it in the initial allocation, no further allocations are required:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "os"
        "runtime"

        "golang.org/x/crypto/chacha20poly1305"
)

func main() {
        showMemUsage("START")

        plaintext := make([]byte, 4<<30, 4<<30+chacha20poly1305.Overhead)

        showMemUsage("STAGE 1")

        key := make([]byte, chacha20poly1305.KeySize)
        if cipher, err := chacha20poly1305.New(key); err == nil {
                showMemUsage("STAGE 2")

                nonce := make([]byte, chacha20poly1305.NonceSize)
                cipher.Seal(plaintext[:0], nonce, plaintext, nil)
        }

        showMemUsage("END")
}

func showMemUsage(tag string) {
        var m runtime.MemStats

        runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout, "[%s] Alloc = %v MiB, TotalAlloc = %v MiB\n", tag, m.Alloc>>20, m.TotalAlloc>>20)
}

// Output:
// [START] Alloc = 0 MiB, TotalAlloc = 0 MiB
// [STAGE 1] Alloc = 4096 MiB, TotalAlloc = 4096 MiB
// [STAGE 2] Alloc = 4096 MiB, TotalAlloc = 4096 MiB
// [END] Alloc = 4096 MiB, TotalAlloc = 4096 MiB
```

> Overhead is the size of the Poly1305 authentication tag, and the difference between a ciphertext length and its plaintext.

Comment: That's a good way of practically solving the issue, but personally I'd still have a big problem if applications unnecessarily take 4 GiB of RAM - even on my 32 GiB development PC's.

Comment: Agreed and what you have described is a flaw in the way Go have implemented the AEAD ciphers. I can find at least 3 issues raised against `crypto/cipher` as it doesn't provide a Streaming API to allow you to encrypt in chunks, but they have all been closed as something they won't support.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this problem exists for many libraries that implement AEAD ciphers unfortunately. One shot implementations are quite common. There is something to be said, as it protects the user against the use of *unverified data* retrieved during decryption. This protection is a bit of a problem if the data is stored to disk; in that case the data isn't directly used and the temp file could be destroyed if the verification tag doesn't match.

It might may be considered a problem if the data will be deserialized to objects as well. Developers should however beware that deserialization of unverified (randomized) data could lead to vulnerabilities getting exposed.

This can be solved in two ways:

1. find a better implementation that does allow streaming;
2. alter the protocol.

---

One such alteration is the splitting of the ciphertext into chunks of a size that comfortably does fit into memory. Then these chunks can be verified individually. That does leave room for adding, removing or shuffling the chunks around though. That can be avoided by adding an additional authentication tag over all the other authentication tags of said chunks.

It would be a good idea to *first check the validity of the authentication tags* before handling the data within the chunks. Those authentication tags could be stored at the start or end of the ciphertext instead of at the end of each chunk to avoid having to pass over the ciphertext twice (which would likely increase the amount of IO ops).

At this point using a stream cipher such as ChaCha20 with HMAC could be more efficient and yes. Don't forget to include the IV in the HMAC calculation in case HMAC is used instead of a pre-made AEAD construction.

---

Regardless of your scheme, please explicitly document it and include a version number with your ciphertext; you may want to upgrade to another protocol...